# When do I use another function without paramters in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm a novice of Kotlin.
I found that I can use another function without parameters even if it has.
Let me know when I can use it.

[image]

Q1) Why can I use 2 types? (with parameters & without parameters) Is it Kotlin's feature?
Q2) What does it mean? ((Result!) -> Unit)!

Comment: that is not without parameters, it is representation of anonymous function you can pass and the `(Result!) -> Unit)!` is the signature of it.

Comment: You should check how lambdas works in Kotlin https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html

Comment: That is most likely when you can talk to `signIn(Session.SignInListener)` except it actually takes a **Java** interface with single method and therefore automatic SAM conversion also lets you pass in a Kotlin lambda of the same type

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are confused, you can never use a function without arguments. If the function has arguments then you have to fill the slot somehow.

The closest thing that could relate to what you are referring to is default values for arguments.

```
fun example(boolean: Boolean = true) {}

example()

example(true)

example(false)
```

You can omit the argument because it has defaulted in the function signature.

The [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html)

What you are showing in the image file is a lambda.

In the first example:

```
signIn(listener: Session...)
```

That seems to be a callback. So it is gonna be an interface or maybe an abstract class called when some async operation is finished.

The second example, it is the callback implemented as a lambda

```
signIn() { result ->
   //do something
}
```

In Kotlin the last argument if it is a lambda or something that can be implemented as a lambda can be moved out of the parenthesis for syntactic sugar. A lambda is like an anonymous function, it is a literal of a function.

By example you can declare a lambda:

```
val lambda = {text: String -> text.lenght % 2 == 0}

fun setRuleForText(rule: (String)-> Boolean) {...}

setRuleForText(lambda)

setRuleForText() { text: String 
    text.isNotEmpty()
}
```

In this case, the argument is a kotlin function. The argument `rule` is a function that receives a `String` as an argument and returns `Boolean`. Something to point out is that expressions return the last written value without the need for the reserved `return` word.

This is the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html). And [here](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/kotlin-programmer-dictionary-function-type-vs-function-literal-vs-lambda-expression-vs-anonymous-edc97e8873e) you can see from a good source more about functions (the author is a Kotlin certified trained by Jetbrains)

In your case `(Result) -> Unit` means the lambda should receive a `Result` type as argument and then return `Unit` (unit is like void in Java but is more than that), no explicit return type.

```
signIn() { result ->
  //do something
}
```

Most of the types, the argument on lambdas is inferred automatically, but if not, then

```
signIn() { result: Result ->
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Both* of the listed functions take a parameter.

The first is:

```
signIn(listener: Session.SignInListener!)
```

That takes a single parameter, of type `Session.SignInListener`.  (The `!` means that Kotlin doesn't know whether it's nullable or not, because it's from Java and isn't annotated.)

The other is:

```
signIn {...} (listener: ((Result!) -> Unit)!)
```

That's the IDE's representation of the function with this signature:

```
signIn(listener: ((Result!) -> Unit)!)
```

That takes a single parameter, which is a function type (see below).

The reason the IDE shows it with braces is that in Kotlin, if the last parameter to a function is a lambda, you can move it outside the parentheses.  So a call like this:

```
signIn({ println(it) })
```

could equally well be written like this:

```
signIn() { println(it) }
```

The two forms mean exactly the same.  And, further, if the lambda is the *only* parameter, you can omit the parens entirely:

```
signIn { println(it) }
```

Again, it means exactly the same thing.

That syntax allows you to write functions that look like new language syntax.  For example:

```
repeat (10) {
    // ...
}
```

looks like a new form of loop construct, but it's really just a function called `repeat`, which takes two parameter (an integer, and a lambda).

OK, let's look at that function type: `((Result!) -> Unit)!`

That's the type of a function which takes one parameter of type `Result`, and returns `Unit` (i.e. nothing useful; think of it as the equivalent of `void`).  Again, it's complicated because Kotlin doesn't know about the nullability; both the `Result` parameter and the parameter holding this function have `!`s to indicate this.  (Without them, it would just be `(Result) -> Unit`.)